# Javascript Delete Method?

Tags: javascript

In this code snippet from AdvancED DOM Scripting:

The call to `delete(classes[i]);` is this an array or object method? I'm unable to Google an answer.

```
/**
 * remove a class from an element 
 */
function removeClassName(element, className) {
    if(!(element = $(element))) return false;
    var classes = getClassNames(element);
    var length = classes.length
    //loop through the array in reverse, deleting matching items
    // You loop in reverse as you're deleting items from 
    // the array which will shorten it.
    for (var i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (classes[i] === className) { delete(classes[i]); }
    }
    element.className = classes.join(' ');
    return (length == classes.length ? false : true);
};
window['ADS']['removeClassName'] = removeClassName;
```

Comment: I found this link relevant : http://www.openjs.com/articles/delete.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mozilla Reference Docs says the following regarding the delete operator:

> The delete operator deletes an object, an object's property, or an element at a specified index in an array.

For more information, see the following article:

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: @jondavidjohn LOL!  It means that it can be used on objects, object properties, and array elements.  Still not clear?  http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: yes, that's a top result in google, but "The delete operator deletes an object..." is a self reliant definition...

Comment: @Phil Klien.Thanks found the article mentioned, during your reply. Most serendipitous. To all, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`delete` will set the value of the specified member (variable/array/object) to `undefined`

array/object example...

since `classes[i]` is actually referencing the `i` index of the array.  It will set that specific index position to undefined, reserving the position in the array...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use simply `$('p').removeClass('myClass yourClass')` with jquery and put together a function to do so for any element